# Advanced Mode not displaying in Content Search Web Part "Change Query"

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, query, cswp

I am having an issue with SharePoint Online. I am trying to integrate CSWP into some pages within a SharePoint site. However, when I attempt to change the query to modify the results, the ability to select "advanced mode" is not available. Any ideas what could be causing this? 
[image: Screenshot of menu]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem -> Within the master page I had added some custom CSS that would hide the left hand navigation. However, when this was hidden, it also hid the extra options within the CSWP change query function. I will need to research how to effectively hide the left hand navigation and keep the functions.